# Issue with fastboot giving remote: Command not allowed

Tags: rooting, fastboot, huawei

I have an Honor 5C that I try to modify bootloader variables. First I need to get the list of variables by doing `fastboot getvar all` but it returns me an annoying:

```
aaaaaaa@bbbbbb:~$ fastboot getvar all
getvar:all FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.005s
```

My phone is rooted, I can do anything with adb, be a superuser on the phone, ask its reboot with fastboot, but this command won't work as I would like. Does anyone has an idea about it ?